# Grails Validation errors as Set or no duplicates

Tags: validation, grails, unique

We have a 1-to-many relationship between a parent Object A and Children B (Contribution) . A field in the child object depends on a specific selection of a field in the parent object. The save of the parent is a cascade so all the validation messages for both the parent and the child occur at the same time.

There is no usable differentiation between the multiple child objects when the validation error occurs (ie there is no name. We could use the ID but the user does not want to see the ID in the UI so it would be pointless). How can I remove duplicate error messages of the children or make it a set so only 1 message of a certain type shows?

```
Object A
    InitiativeType initiative
    static hasMany = [ contributions: Contribution ] 

Contribution
    SpecialCategory specialCategory

    static constraints = {
        specialCategory nullable: true, validator: { val, obj ->
                if ((val && val.id > 53 && val.id < 75) && !obj.A.initiative?.contains(5) ) { // special initiative
                    return ['specialValidation']
                }
            }
```

Certain IDs in SpecialCategory will only be valid if a certain Initiative ID is selected. Otherwise, throw the validation error stating "Special Category [ID] requires you to select Initiative [Required_Initiative_Name]"

As it stands, it is possible to see the same error message multiple times if a user creates multiple Contributions that use the same SpecialCategory ID and not having selected the appropriate Initiative. Can the validation messages be a set? Or do I have to loop through all the errors and attempt to remove the dupes (gross)?

There are better ways to handle this (such as not showing the certain SpecialCategories in the select when the Specific Initiative isn't selected) but this is what the user group requested. I'm currently on pushing on doing it a more correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to break up my error output block in my GSP. This seems to work fine:

```
<g:eachError var="err" bean="${A}">
    <g:if test="${err.code != 'specialValidation'}"> <!-- show message later to remove duplicates -->
        <g:message error="${err}" /><br />
    </g:if>
</g:eachError>
<g:if test="${A?.contributions?.errors?.size == 1}">
    A Contribution with a Special Category must also include the Special Initiative.
</g:if><g:elseif test="${A?.contributions?.errors?.size > 1}">
    Contributions with a Special Category must also include the Special Initiative. There are currently ${a?.contributions?.errors?.size} in error.
</g:elseif>
```